# Find two nonnegative numbers $x$ and $y$ whose sum is $15$ and $P=x^2 y^3$ is a maximum.

Tags: calculus

Please someone help

Find two nonnegative numbers $x$ and $y$ whose sum is $15$ and $$P=x^2 y^3$$ is a maximum.

I have reached to

$$(15-x)^2  (- 3x^2  + 30x-2x^2)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$x+y=15$$

Using AM-GM inequality

$$\dfrac{2\cdot\dfrac x2+3\cdot\dfrac y3}{2+3}\ge\sqrt[2+3]{\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2\left(\dfrac y3\right)^3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you have two $x^2$ terms in the second set of parentheses. There are a few simple steps you can take to simplify this expression further.

Answer (score 0):

$$P=x^2 y^3=x^2(15-x)^3$$
$$\frac{dP}{dx}=2x(15-x)^3-3x^2(15-x)^2$$

For some $x$, if P is at it's maximum value, $\frac{dP}{dx}=0$

$$\frac{dP}{dx}=2x(15-x)^3-3x^2(15-x)^2=0$$
$$2x(15-x)^3=3x^2(15-x)^2$$
$$2(15-x)=3x$$
$$30=5x$$
$$x=6, y=9$$

To verify if the maxima exists at the above coordinate:
$$ \frac{d^2P}{dx^2}_{(6)}<0$$
$$\frac{dP}{dx}=2x(15-x)^3-3x^2(15-x)^2=0$$
$$\frac{d^2P}{dx^2}=2(15-x)^3-6x(15-x)^2-6x(15-x)^2+6x(15-x)$$
$$=2(15-6)^3-12(6)(15-6)^2+6(6)(15-6)=-4050<0$$

The maximum value of $P=x^2y^3$ exists at $(6,9)$, and is $36*729=26244$